# SQL query to select rows on date added where when they expired in a field in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a date_added column and an expiry time, set in days.

I have tried the following:

```
select * 
from `claims` 
where date_added(`date_added`, interval `expire_period` day) < date(now())
```

I have tried reformatting and still getting an error.

This is solved:

> SELECT *
>   FROM `dk`.`claims`
>   WHERE DATE_ADD(`date_added`, interval `expire_period` day) < date(now());

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's the error message you are getting?

Comment: Others have already given the answer to your question, below.  However, it may be worth noting that you will achieve better performance by storing `expiry_date` instead of `expire_period` - especially if that column is then indexed.

Comment: The error message was as per below last answer, but I figured out my problem, syntax left out the damn semicolon at the end.

Comment: The missing semicolon is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. There is no function `date_added`. What you need is [`date_add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

```
SELECT * 
FROM claims 
WHERE DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL expire_period DAY) < DATE(NOW());
```

Your error message will have told you something like:

> SQL ERROR (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that correcsponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') < date(now())' at line 1.

So it did not know what to do with the closing bracket. From there, you can track back to see where the open bracket is. Next to `date_added`. And that is not a function.

You can also rely on the database client. I'm using HeidiSQL on Windows, and it highlights all keywords (including functions). The `date_added` is not blue in your query.

Comment: +simbabque. You are correct in what you say. I was busy going through the syntax before I posted and where it was date_add got me confused as the column in my table is date_added and I amended it. But it still did not work as I was missing the semi colon at the end. I could not amend the above query as someone had already posted a reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from claims 
where date_add(date_added, interval expire_period day) < date(now())
```

[Reference of DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)